# More efficient method to grab one word from string based on an index?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, string

I'm trying to write a Bash completion script which doesn't break in the presence of colons. To do this, I'm using COMP_LINE to determine the string for the command, and COMP_POINT as the index of which character in the command the user is currently pointing to.

Using these two variables, I want to work out which word the user is currently trying to complete. This would normally be done using the COMP_WORDS array, with the COMP_CWORD variable acting as a pointer to that array. The problem is, COMP_WORDS splits strings on colons, so that a command such as:

```
dothis foo:bar
```

Is read into COMP_WORDS as:

```
('dothis' 'foo' ':' 'bar')
```

I don't want this behaviour, so I'm working around it.

So say I have a command stored in in a Bash variable which looks like this:

```
apple banana carrot:cucumber  durian
```

My current solution to the stated problem is below. The explanation is below the code, as honestly I think the code is simpler.

```
#!/bin/bash

str="apple banana carrot:cucumber  durian"
cur=29
char=${str:$cur:1} # Current character being pointed to
prev=${str:$cur-1:1} # Previous character

if [[ $char == [[:space:]] ]]; then
    if [[ $prev == [[:space:]] ]]; then
        # Rule 1 - Char and prev are whitespace
        # apple banana carrot:cucumber  durian
        #                              ^ Char = ' ' Prev = ' '
        word=""
    else
        # Rule 2 - Char is whitespace, prev is not
        # apple banana
        #      ^ Char = ' ' Prev = 'e'
        # Means prev is the last character of the word
        slice="${str::$cur}"
        word="${slice##* }" # 'apple'
    fi
else
    if [[ $prev == [[:space:]] ]]; then
        # Rule 3 - Char is not whitespace, prev is whitespace
        # apple banana carrot:cucumber
        #              ^ Char = 'c' Prev = ' '
        slice="${str:$cur}"
        word="${slice%% *}" # 'carrot:cucumber'
    else
        # Rule 4 - Char and prev are not whitespace
        # apple banana
        #          ^ Char = 'a' Prev = 'n'
        end="${str:$cur}"
        end="${end#* }"
        slice="${str% $end}"
        word="${slice##* }" # 'banana'
    fi
fi
echo "Word: <$word>"
```

What this does is the following. It checks the character at the index (char) and the character before that (prev) and follows these four rules to determine what word is currently being pointed to:

1. If char and prev are both whitespace characters, then set 'word' to empty
2. If char is whitespace but prev is a non-whitespace character, then take 'prev' to be the end of the word. Extract a substring up until prev, and then remove everything from the start of that substring up to and including a space.
3. If char is a non-whitespace character but prev is whitespace, then take 'char' to be the start of a word. Extract a substring up until prev, then remove everything from the end of the substring up to and including a space.
4. If char and prev are both non-whitespace characters, then take 'char' to be either the middle or end of a word. First grab a substring from 'char' to the end of the string, then from the start of that substring, remove the shortest instance of text up to and including a space. Then remove *that* substring from the original string, to get everything up to the word. Lastly from *that* substring, remove everything up to and including a space to get just the word.

---

Basically **I'm not convinced this is the most efficient solution**. It's complicated to even describe in a question. Surely there's some better, hacky way to grab a whole word from a string based on an index to that word?

Can anyone offer a suggestion on a better approach to this problem, or if not, any way to optimise the solution that I have?

Comment: FWIW, I could get around the XY problem by changing `COMP_WORDBREAKS` so that it doesn't break on colons, but this might break other completion scripts so don't want to do this.

Comment: I'm also aware that [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12495727/1907765) exists which suggests using helper variables to solve the colon problem, but I haven't had success in implementing their code and haven't found any documentation on the internet to support that solution.